# Nativescript Angular IOS : Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." when uploading files

Tags: ios, swift, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

When I am trying to upload files in the slower networks I get the below error in the xcode

[image]

Upload Code :

```js
uploadPhotos(): void {
        let message;
        this.photos = this.service.getPhotosToUpload();
        if (this.photos !== null && this.photos.length > 0) {
            const photosList$ = new Array<Observable<boolean[]>>;

            this.photos.forEach(photo=> {
                const observable = this.submitPhoto(photo)
                if (observable) {
                    photosList$.push(observable);
                }

            });

            zip(photosList$)
                .pipe(
                    switchMap((flags: boolean[][], index: number) => {
                        let totalNotuploaded = 0;
                        let totalUploaded = 0;
                        const results =[]
                        flags.forEach((flag) => {
                            totalNotuploaded += flag.filter(falses => !falses).length;
                            totalUploaded += flag.filter(trues => trues).length;
                        });
                        results.push([totalNotuploaded, totalUploaded])
                        return of(results);
                    })
                ).subscribe((results: number[][]) => {
                    let notuploaded = results[0][0] ;
                    let uploaded = results[0][1];

                    this.message = `Uploaded ${uploaded} Photo(s).`;

                    if (notuploaded > 0) {
                        this.message += `Errors uploading ${notuploaded}`
                    
                    }
                });


        } else {
            this.message = `Uploaded 0 Photos.`;
        }
    }

    submitPhoto(photo: PhotoWrapper): Observable<boolean[]> {

        const photosToUpload$ = new Array<Observable<boolean>>();
        const photosToUpload = photo.filter((filter) => !filter.Uploaded);

        photosToUpload.forEach(photo => {

            photo.FileContent = this.servic.getFileAsBase64String(new Path(photo.File.directory as any, photo.File.relativePath));
            const observable = this.service.upload(photo);
            photosToUpload$.push(
                observable.pipe(
                    catchError(() => {
                        return of(null)
                    }),
                    switchMap((result: PhotoResult) => {
                        return of(result && result?.flag ? true : false)
                    })
                ));
        });
        if (photosToUpload$ && photosToUpload$.length) {
            return forkJoin(photosToUpload$);
        } else { return null; }

    }
    
    //upload service
    
    upload(photosData: PhotoWrapper): Observable<PhotoResult> {
        let headers = this.authService.getAuthHeader();
        let url = this.configurationService.uploadPhotoUrl();

        return this.http.post<boolean>(this.configurationService.uploadPhotoUrl(), photoDto, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
            map((result) =>( {flag: result.body, wrapper: photosData} as PhotoResult)),
            
            );
    }

}
```

When connected to a strong network LTE 3 or more bars ,5g or WIFI , I am able to upload files without any issues.

How can I increase the timeout or how can I prevent the NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." error please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used native script http instead of angular httpclient and increased the timeout

```js
const httprequestOption  = {
             url : 'url',
             method : 'POST',
             headers : {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`
             },
             content: JSON.stringify(dto),
             timeout : 900000 //Increase Default Timeout
        } as HttpRequestOptions;
          return from(Http.request(httprequestOption).then((response) => {
            const result = response.content.toString();
            return result;
          })
```